# How to not print a space after a comma

Tags: python, output

This is my current code. The print will put a space prior to the "!" and I've searched the forums for an hour, but everything is way too complicated for me right now. It's a stupid question, but I have to know why it's adding this random space after a comma.

```
fn = input("What's your First Name? ")
ln = input("What's your Last Name? ")
print ('Hello,',fn, ln,'!')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you print a list of strings python inserts a space.

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (v3.5.3:1880cb95a742, Jan 16 2017, 08:49:46)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('My','name','is','doug')
My name is doug
>>> print('My'+'name'+'is'+'doug')
Mynameisdoug
```

You want to either combine you elements into a single string  OR (the better way)  use string formatting to output.

```
>>> fn = "Bob"
>>> ln = "Jones"
>>> msg = "Hello, "+fn+" "+ln+"!"
>>> print(msg)
Hello, Bob Jones!
>>> msg = "Hello, {0} {1}!".format(fn,ln)
>>> print(msg)
Hello, Bob Jones!
>>>
```

Answer (score 5):

> It's a stupid question, but I have to know why it's adding this random
>   space after a comma.

The default setting of print is such that comma adds whitespace after it.

One way of removing the space before `!` here is doing :

```
print('Hello,',fn, ln, end='')
print('!')

Out : Hello, First Last!
```

Here the `end=` specifies what should be printed upon end of print() statement instead of the `default newline`.

Another far more easier method is just to `concatenate` the string. ie,

```
print('Hello,',fn, ln + '!')
```

Answer (score 4):

in python 3.6 you could use `f`strings which are well readable and slightly faster than the other format-methods :

```
print(f'Hello {fn} {ln}!')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for format strings.

Python 3:

```
print('Hello {} {}!'.format(fn, ln))
```

Python 2:

```
print 'Hello %s %s!' % (fn, ln)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the element before  the exclamation mark (`ln`) and concatenate the `'!'` on to the end:

```
fn = input("What's your First Name? ")
ln = input("What's your Last Name? ")
print ('Hello,', fn, ln + '!')
```

giving:

```
Hello, Fist Last!
```

The `print()` statement documentation states that:

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does and written to the stream, separated by sep

and since by default, `sep` is a space `(' ')`, you get spaces between each of the arguments you passed into the `function`. As above, if you concatenate the exclamation mark onto `ln` yourself, the default `sep` parameter is not inserted and you will not get a space.

Comment: The convert `ln` to string is unnecessary as `ln` is already a string

Comment: @KaushikNP I realized this when adding the documentation! Thank you :)